# How to know what type is the data sent?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I've got this function where I retrive some datas sent during some functions:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, forRecipient recipient: GKPlayer, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
    print("RECEIVED DATA 9.0")
        receiveData(turnLog: data, player: player)
        receiveDataAction(movment: data, player: player)
        receiveDataActionTop(movmentTop: data, player: player)
}
```

But obviously every func that I call is related to a specific data. How can I know the "type" of data that I'm receiving to create an if-else statement?

I send this data like this:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let dataMovment = try! encoder.encode(SKActionDescriptor(x: 450, duration: 0.25, x2: 1050, duration2: 0.5))
try match?.sendData(toAllPlayers: dataMovment, with: GKMatchSendDataMode.reliable)
```

Comment: A possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999841/how-can-i-exchange-various-types-data-through-nsdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That entirely depends on what kind of data you're sending through. It's up to you to set up a system where the receiver can figure out what data it's dealing with.

Generally, there are 2 ways.

1. Either the schema (the "layout" of the data) is communicated as part of the data. e.g. JSON, where the `[ ]`/`{ }` communicate the structure of the fields. When you get a chunk of JSON, you don't know how long the first object in array goes on for. It starts at the `{`, and goes on until the matching `}`. The JSON itself encodes a description of its own layout.
2. The schema is protocol-defined, and isn't transmitted. A receiver that correctly implements that protocol will expect the data coming into it to match the constraints defined in the protocol. For example a UDP packet, which is just "raw" data, whose schema isn't transmitted, but rather, is defined by the protocol:

   - The first 2 bytes encode the source port
   - The second 2 bytes encode the destination port
   - The next 2 bytes encode the payload size
   - The next 2 bytes encode the checksum for the packet
   - The next n bytes constitute the payload.

   None of this structural information is self-described by the packet. Rather, it's defined by the UDP protocol, and any sender/receiver that "plays nice" is expected to follow that schema.

Comment: your answer was very exhaustive but unfortunately I almost know nothing about the passage of data between devices, now I edit the post to show how the data is sent... could you please update your answer maybe with a few lines of code to make me understand better what I have to do?

Comment: I can't, I've never dealt with this before. But it looks like your using JSON. So you can wrap your payload with an object that stores two fields, a "Type",  and a "Payload". Your receiver can then check the Type field to see what type it needs to use to decode the payload.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean but unfortunately I don't know how recreate it in code...

Comment: @AndreaCulot Start by making a codable struct called `GameKitMessage<Payload>`, with `type: String` and `payload: Payload` members. Then wrap all your transmissions in that struct, and send those structs, rather than the raw payloads on your own